# Is a rogue with the Use Magic Device feature considered proficient in armor and weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

In the Dungeon Master's Guide for the Use Magic Device feature of a rogue it says on page 141 that "your proficiency bonus does apply" for a magical staff. Does this count as being proficient in the item? If so could a rogue wear magical platemail or use a longbow with no downside?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> **Spells** [...] A magic item, such as certain staffs, may require you to use your own spellcasting ability when you cast a spell from the item.
>   If you have more than one spellcasting ability, you choose which one
>   to use with the item. If you don't have a spellcasting ability-perhaps
>   you're a rogue with the Use Magic Device feature- your spellcasting
>   ability modifier is +0 for the item, and your proficiency bonus does
>   apply. (DMG 141)

I have quoted the whole paragraph and the title to clear up the misunderstanding. The half-sentence you quote refers only to casting spells from a magic item and the use of a spellcasting ability when you do so. It does not mean that you are considered proficient with all uses of the item, just spellcasting.

Answer (score 1):

> **USE MAGIC DEVICE**
>   By 13th level, you have learned enough about the workings of magic that you can improvise the use of items even when they are not intended for you. ***You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of magic items.***  [PHB, pg 97]

You do not gain proficiency, only the ability to use.